# Topology and continuity from right

Tags: general-topology, continuity

How do we define continuity from right on an ordered set with the order topology, using the specific definition of continuity which is inverse image of an open set is open?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define it as follows.  A function $f:X\to Y$, where $X$ is an ordered set with the order topology and $Y$ is a topological space is continuous from the right at a point $x\in X$ if $x$ is the largest element of the set $X$ or, otherwise, for each neighborhood $U$ of the point $f(x)$ 
there exists a point $y\in X$ such that $y>x$ and $f([x,y))\subset U$.